# Reduction of independence to uncorrelatedness

Tags: probability-theory

Consider two random variables $Y, Z \in \mathbb R$. Someone claims that $Y$ is independent of $Z$ if and only if $1\{Y \ge t\}$ is uncorrelated with $Z$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. Is this true?

The statement seems suspect to me. I can see that they are independent iff $1\{Y \ge t\}$ is uncorrelated with $1\{Z \ge s\}$ for all $s,t \in \mathbb R$. But not the above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $1\{Y\ge t\}$ is uncorrelated with $Z$ for all $t\in \Bbb R$, we can show that $Y$ itself is uncorrelated with $Z$. To do this, first assume $Y\ge 0$ for simplicity. I use this trick to relate $Y$ to $1\{Y\ge t\}$:
$$
Y=\int_0^\infty 1\{Y\ge t\}\,dt \tag 1
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
E[YZ]
&=E\left[Z\int_0^\infty 1\{Y\ge t\}\,dt\right]
\\&=\int_0^\infty E[Z1\{Y\ge t\}]\,dt
\\&=\int_0^\infty E[Z]E[1\{Y\ge t\}]\,dt
\\&=E[Z]\int_0^\infty P(Y\ge t)\,dt
\\&=E[Z]E[Y]
\end{align}
$$
To exchange the order of $\int$ and $E[]$, you can use Fubini's theorem. When $Y$ can be negative, replace $(1)$ with $Y = \int_0^\infty [1\{Y\ge t\}-1\{Y\le -t\}]\,dt$.

Therefore, it makes sense to look for an example of $Y$ and $Z$ which are uncorrelated but dependent, and hope that we additionally have $1_{Y\ge t}$ being uncorrelated with $Z$.

One common example of uncorrelated and dependent random variables is when $Y$ and $Z$ are given by the following joint pmf:

|  | $Z=-1$ | $Z=0$ | $Z=1$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| $Y=-1$ | 0 | $\frac14$ | 0 |
| $Y=0$ | $\frac14$ | 0 | $\frac14$ |
| $Y=1$ | 0 | $\frac14$ | 0 |

You can check that $1_{Y\ge t}$ is uncorrelated with $Z$ for all $t$, so this is a counterexample which solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting example. In your argument using the integrals, are you saying $P(Y > t | Z) = P(Y > t)$ for all $t$? Wouldn't that be equivalent to the independence of $Y$ and $Z$ which is not what we assume?

Comment: @passerby51 Good point, that's something I thought made sense at the time, but on reflection does not. See edit.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Looks great now.